# Golang templates : how to define array in a variable?

Tags: arrays, templates, variables, go

What would be the correct syntax to define an array variable inside a go template ? (here a HTML template). Here's what I tried :

```
{{define "template"}}
    {{ $x:=[]int{0,1,2} }}{{$x[0]}}
{{end}}
```

The error log says : `unexpected "[" in command`

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

there is no built-in way to do what you want to achieve. See the [arguments](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Arguments) on what you can do with the arguments and the pipeline.

But you could easily define your own function to achieve your goal:

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "os"
)

func main() {
tmpl := `
{{ $slice := mkSlice "a" 5 "b" }}
{{ range $slice }}
     {{ . }}
{{ end }}
`
    funcMap := map[string]interface{}{"mkSlice": mkSlice}
    t := template.New("demo").Funcs(template.FuncMap(funcMap))
    template.Must(t.Parse(tmpl))
    t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "demo", nil)
}

func mkSlice(args ...interface{}) []interface{} {
    return args
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/6CZOdfw5FT).

Answer (score 8):

You can use the sprig library to help here (I'm using this for helm templates - which are go templates, but helm has sprig builtin)

```
$myList := list  0 1 2
$new = append $myList 3
```

From [Sprig Lists](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/lists.html)

Comment: any way to create a map in helm/go template ?

Comment: What can we do if we have strings and not integers?